# Is it On-Topic to ask a question about Work from Home Issues in workplace SE site? (We have been working remotely due to Covid19)

Tags: discussion, scope, covid-19

As we all have been working from home or remotely due to Covid-19, our work place has been changed to home. So if we now face any issue related to work, is it suitable to ask it in The Workplace or do we need to a new site (proposal) for this?

Answer (score 22):

Given the (currently) 224 questions in the [telecommute](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/telecommute) tag, it's absolutely fine (provided it meets the other criteria mentioned in the [Help Center](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)). The Workplace isn't just a physical place; at home you can be equally interacting with your colleagues and customers.

Comment: I second this answer!

Comment: We also get a fair number of questions about handling client relations and related issues from the perspective of independent contractors and what format that work takes (i.e. in-person or remote) has had nothing to do with the topicality of such questions so far. Ask away!

Answer (score 5):

To add to the [other answer](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6747/61983) provided by Glorfindel, we have the term (now more than even) "Home Office", so as long as the question is [about navigating in the workplace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help) (be it a HQ, regional office, or as you ask - about home office), it should be fine.

Answer (score 2):

I have a workshop/lab/office at home, 1/4 the problems I get are work related and would be on topic, the other 3/4's are caused by my kids creating havoc, which probably aren't.

Comment: Feel free to come over to [Parenting.se] for those :)

Comment: @Joe they're not a problem, just full of energy. Self employed working on my own timeframes so I often just drop work for a while and join them.